# keyframes for mp4s with ffmpeg and ffprobe

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, mp4, jwplayer, ffprobe

I'm trying to create a mp4 video with keyframes (aka i-frames) so I can do [pseudostreaming](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28855/pseudo-streaming-in-flash/) with flash as suggested by [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/).  I'm using [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and [ffprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html).  When I run `./ffprobe.exe -show_frames -i myVideo.mp4` I see a lot of output where the only key frames that exist are `key_frame=0` and `key_frame=1`.  How can I make my mp4 video have more keyframes?  I'd be happy to use ffmpeg, Any Video Converter, Avidemux, or any other program that runs with Windows 7.

Comment: One program I would recommend to check out is - http://handbrake.fr/